# TinyXml and Strings

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, tinyxml

I'm trying to read an xml file's attributes where I'm storing information. I need to retrieve that information in the form of strings and I'm unable to do that since I cant find any tinyXml method that would return a string and I cant figure out a way to convert things from char* to String^. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In TinyXML you can get XmlElements attribute with Attribute() function. It returns `const char *` which can be converted to string as Adrian have stated in his/her answer according to http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ with `string ( const char * s )`.

More about the Attribute function: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html#e419a442a9701a62b0c3d8fd1cbdd12d

Comment: Didn't downvote, but my guess would be they downvoter might have felt the answer is still to dependant on the link contents.  Answers should be able to stand on their own without the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert `char *` to `string`.
According to http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ C++ `string` has this ctor: `string ( const char * s )`